# Laravel 8: uploaded image shows 403 forbidden error

Tags: php, laravel, solid-principles

I created a service class `LostFoundService` with this function:

```
public function storeLostFound(Request $request)
    {
        // Upload Images
        $LFImage = ($request->hasFile('LFImage'))
            ? $request->file('LFImage')->store('lostFound/lostItems')
            : NULL;

        $handoverImage = ($request->hasFile('handoverStatement'))
            ? $request->file('handoverStatement')->store('lostFound/handoverStatements')
            : NULL;

        // Create a new instance
        return LostFound::create([
            'LFNumber'              => $request->LFNumber,
            'claimingDate'          => $request->claimingDate,
            'lostItem'              => $request->lostItem,
            'zoneNumber'            => $request->zoneNumber,
            'receivedDate'          => $request->receivedDate,
            'lostLocation'          => $request->lostLocation,
            'foundBy'               => $request->foundBy,
            'claimedBy'             => $request->claimedBy,
            'LFAction'              => $request->LFAction,
            'LFImage'               => $LFImage,
            'handoverStatement'     => $handoverImage,
            'handover'              => $request->handover,
            'cccEmployee'           => $request->cccEmployee,
        ]);
    }
```

And then calling it in the controller:

```
// Add new Record.
    public function store(LostFoundRequest $request, LostFoundService $lostFoundService)
    {
        $lostFoundService->storeLostFound($request);
        return redirect( route('data-entry.lost-and-found.index') )->with('success', 'Item Added Successfully');
    }
```

The code block above works fine without the `403 Forbidden`. However, it violates the **Single Responsibility principle**: it creates the `lostFound` and uploads the files.

So I decided to change the service to the following (Which is where I get the 403 forbidden):

```
public function storeLostFound(array $LFData): LostFound
    {
        // Create a new instance
        $lostFound = LostFound::create([
            'LFNumber'              => $LFData['LFNumber'],
            'claimingDate'          => $LFData['claimingDate'],
            'lostItem'              => $LFData['lostItem'],
            'zoneNumber'            => $LFData['zoneNumber'],
            'receivedDate'          => $LFData['receivedDate'],
            'lostLocation'          => $LFData['lostLocation'],
            'foundBy'               => $LFData['foundBy'],
            'claimedBy'             => $LFData['claimedBy'],
            'LFAction'              => $LFData['LFAction'],
            'LFImage'               => $LFData['LFImage'],
            'handoverStatement'     => $LFData['handoverStatement'],
            'handover'              => $LFData['handover'],
            'cccEmployee'           => $LFData['cccEmployee'],
        ]);
        return $lostFound;
    }

    public function uploadImages(Request $request)
    {
        return ($request->hasFile('LFImage'))
            ? $request->file('LFImage')->store('/lostFound/lostItems')
            : NULL;
    }
```

Then in the controller:

```
// Add new Record.
    public function store(LostFoundRequest $request, LostFoundService $lostFoundService)
    {
        $LFImage = $lostFoundService->uploadImages($request);
        $lostFoundService->storeLostFound($request->validated() + ['LFImage' => $LFImage]);
        return redirect( route('data-entry.lost-and-found.index') )->with('success', 'Item Added Successfully');
    }
```

Why am I getting the `403 Forbidden` for the uploaded images?

Comment: when do you get the 403?  What is the error?

Comment: Ensure that the return value of the authorise method in your custom request object is true.

Comment: @Snapey The image should display in the datatable..It isn't, when I open the image in a new tab I get the error

Comment: @Peppermintology It's true

Comment: So the image route is protected?

Comment: @Snapey I don't think so, I don't have any protection for the routes